# sys_connect_by_path in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

Please help me to convert the below query in MSSQL.

```
select sys_connect_by_path(title, '/') "Path", ITEM_ID, PARENT_ID
from lib_items 
where item_type = '1'start with title = 'root'
connect by prior item_id = parent_id
```

Comment: What does this query do?

Comment: It will display the path of child and parent id.

Comment: I mean what sys_connect_by_path(title, '/') and item_type = '1'start with title = 'root' and  connect by prior item_id = parent_id does. Also which database this query belongs to?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to manipulate XML?  Can you post a sample string? More information is better than less.

Comment: It would help to say what RDBMS you are converting from. The `sql-server` tag will mostly attract people that know about SQL Server and they may not know what `sys_connect_by_path` means (or the peculiars used in this query).

Answer (score 1):

IN SQL-Server using a recursive common table expression  like this:

```
; WITH lib_items(title, item_id, parent_id)
       AS   (  SELECT title, item_id, parent_id
               FROM     (VALUES     ('root'  , 1, NULL)
                                ,   ('child1', 2, 1)
                                ,   ('child2', 3, 2)
                                ,   ('child3', 4, 1)
                                )   AS lib_items (title, item_id, parent_id)

           )
   ,  CTE AS
           (   SELECT   CAST (title AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS title, item_id, parent_id
               FROM     lib_items   
               WHERE    parent_id IS NULL
               UNION ALL
               SELECT   CAST(P.Title + '\' +C.Title AS VARCHAR(8000)), C.item_id, C.parent_id
               FROM     lib_items AS c 
               JOIN     CTE AS p ON c.parent_id = p.item_id
           )

SELECT   title, item_id, parent_id
FROM     CTE
```

Result:

```
title              |item_id|parent_id
-------------------|----------------
root               | 1     | NULL
root\child1        | 2     | 1
root\child3        | 4     | 1
root\child1\child2 | 3     | 2
```